# HTML/CSS default border with: 1.5px oder 3px?

Tags: html, css

What's the default border width in HTML/CSS? On various online sources, I read the default border width is medium = 3px on each side.

However, when testing it out myself (on Chrome), the default width is 1.5px on each side and not 3px (if I do not specify a width and just specify border-color and border-style).

Why is that? What is correct here?

I set
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;

and expected it to be 3px width on each side like online sources say, but it's 1.5px instead.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

The border width default is NOT medium by default in my browser for some reason. If I would set it to medium, it's 3px. But like that (so, by default), it's 1.5px.

```html
<p style="border-style: solid;border-color: black;">C:</p>
<p style="border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-width: medium;">C:</p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width#formal_definition tells you that the default is `medium`, and if you follow the links to one of the individual properties, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-width, there you'll find: _"Note: Because the specification doesn't define the exact thickness denoted by each keyword, the precise result when using one of them is implementation-specific. Nevertheless, they always follow the pattern thin ≤ medium ≤ thick, and the values are constant within a single document."_

Comment: The thing is: if I specify border-width: medium in my chrome browser, I do get a width of around 3px as well.

If I do not specify it, however, the width is 1.5px. Meaning the default width in my browser is not "medium" at all

Comment: @CBroe I have attached a screenshot to my question - I hope that helps explain my confusion

Comment: @AlessioGravili Your browser behaves in an odd way. I edited your answer including the snippet as you showed in the picture. Those 2 paragraphs are expected to have the same border and so it does here both on Chrome and Firefox latest versions

Comment: @DiegoD that's veery strange. I'm getting the same result on both chrome canary and chrome. Will need to put more research into this and maybe try it on a different device

Comment: to say the whole truth, I was testing it on Chrome and it worked correctly as I stated.. but on firefox there are some slight differences actually. So my previous statement is not 100% correct. But talking about Chrome (v110) I can assure you that snippet renders 2 paragraphs having the same border. Firefox (v109) shows the second p with a thinner border. So to make it safe maybe you should set explicitely the border when setting `border-style`...yes I know that both were expected to be medium anyway but the default medium translates to 3px and explicit medium to 2.23333px

Answer (score 0):

I tested with this code:

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <div style="width:100px;height:100px;border-color:black;background:gray;border-style:solid">   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

So fore me all standard edge widths are the same: 3px.
Also when I set the width to medium: still all 3px.

[image: standard edge width]

Which browser are you using?

Check if you haven't set a border of some parent